# Angular Components - Output encapsulating a BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component with an internal state, stored in a RxJS `BehaviorSubject` (containing the size of a certain DOM element, by the way).

I would like to expose this state as an `@Output()` property.

The most naive implementation I can think of is this:

```js
// inside myComponent

private _state$ = new BehaviorSubject<Something>(...);

@Output() stateChange = new EventEmitter<Something>();

constructor() {
  // skipping unsubscription for the sake of this simplistic example
  this._state$.subscribe(newState => this.stateChange.emit(newState);
}
```

However, this will NOT emit the currently stored value as a `BehaviorSubject` does as soon as there is a new subscription. Late subscribers are not going to get the current value.

Is there a simple approach for cases like this? I would like to expose the state and basically stop worrying about the order of the events, as I do with a simple `BehaviorSubject<T>`.

Comment: Is there a problem with exposing `this._state$.asObservable()`? Edit: I guess the issue is that you want to bind to it like `(stateChange)="onStateChange($event)"`?

Comment: @KurtHamilton yep, I want to use `(stateChange)` syntax. And, I would like to not care when the parent component is going to subscribe.

Comment: It's a fairly interesting problem. In the absence of a clean way of doing this (the dirty way being forking EventEmitter and inheriting from BehaviorSubject), I've come to the conclusion that's it's probably not good practice to mix the metaphors of javascript event handling and rxjs (despite Angular being quite happy to do this... for now). I'm interested to see what you end up doing though, so please do alert me via this comment chain if you come up with a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

[EventEmitter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/9.0.0/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts) in Angular is a simple extension of RxJS Subject. So theoretically we should be able to achieve your expected behavior by creating a custom emitter by extending `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. A crude implementation would be:

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    
export class BehaviorEventEmitter<T extends any> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  constructor(initial: any) {
    super(<any>(initial));
  }

  emit(value?: T) { super.next(value); }
}
```

One drawback I can see is that it will emit the value of the `initial` argument as soon the related component is loaded in the DOM if no other value has been emitted yet.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6vrvq)

Answer (score -1):

you need to update your behaviourSubject value in your child component like below

`this._state$.next(somevalue);`

then the behaviourSubject subscription will emit the statechange output decorator.

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfjzwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Yes, I know how to emit a value from a Subject. The problem is: "what if the PARENT component is not yet subscribed?"

Comment: if possible can you make it in stackblitz.com